# Fundamental OOP in Tkinter

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, tkinter

I'm relatively new to OOPs and thus know it theoretically. I need a project to be implemented in Tkinter. So, I was going through it. I was just playing around with the most basic code like below

```
# https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Introduction_to_GUI_Programming.html
import tkinter as tk

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent


root = tk.Tk()
app = MainApplication(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Here, I can say confidently that `MainApplication` inherits tk.Frame. So, the `root` is a `TK object` and it is passed in `MainApplication constructor` which assigns it as the `parent` of the `MainApplication` object.

So, when we call the `app.mainloop()`, the `MainApplication object` is called which in turn can invoke the `root` somehow because we have the `root` as a `parent` of the `app object`.

Correct me if I understood it wrong.

Now, as I browsed and another popular method people are using is

```
# https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program
import tkinter as tk

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent


root = tk.Tk()
MainApplication(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Here also, as I can understand the `MainApplication` is invoked and `root` becomes the `parent` of it. But how does that ***link*** the `MainApplication object` with the `root object`, so that when the `root.mainloop()` is called, it can refer back to `MainApplication object`?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more about the actual structure of the `tkinter` module than it is about OOP principles.

`mainloop` is a method of the `Misc` class, which is an ancestor of both `Tk` and `Frame`. When called, it essentially calls the `mainloop` method using a reference it has to the root Tk object, so whether you invoke it from `root` or `app`, the result is the same.